# Adding row to the TableView when Button action

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode6

I have two ViewControls.
In FirstViewControl i have button and,
In SecondViewControl i have TableView,
When i click on button it should go to the TableView(SecondViewControl) and add one row ,how can i do it with programatically.I did not getting sufficient answers.Can any one help me

Comment: they are on same view Controllers
?you can add data on data source of table view of second view controller and reload on viewDidLoad

Comment: No they are in different view controllers. Button in first View Controller and Table is in second view controller

Comment: Are You passing Value on button click??

Comment: on button click add data in array ,pass in second view controller and use in second view controller as data source.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you should do is to create an `NSMutableArray` property in `FirstViewController`. That array needs to be filled in with all data that will be displayed on `SecondViewController`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfData;
```

Also create a `NSMutableArray` property in `SecondViewController`. Now when you have two properties that are capable of holding data, you can go to step when Button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction)buttonInCellPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [arrayOdData addObject:@"E.g. some string.";
    // Call transition to second view after button is clicked
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"GoToSecondViewController" sender: self];
}
```

Code above will add new element to the array, based on what you want to add you will need some customization. Once perform segue is called you will need to copy data before view is actually displayed. You will do that in `prepareForSegue` method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // This string needs to be equal to one that you put in performSegue and on that is in storyboard
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GoToSecondViewController"])
    {
        SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        // This is array in second view controller
        vc.arrayOfData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:oldArray];
    }
}
```

Now in the new controller, use `arrayOfData` to fill in `TableView`. Also, for this solution you will need to return array to the first controller, same process as you did when you send it to second one.

If you want to improve your code, you will need to implement some object that will hold data separately from views.